# Replace missing values in time series data with python (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have time series data from pharmaceutical drug regimens that's essentially structured as: 'patient', 'drug', 'start_day', 'end_day'. Many of the 'end_day' values are nans, and I would like to replace those with the subsequent 'start_day' value. Here's an example to illustrate what groups in the dataframe with missing values look like now:

```
| patient  | drug |start_day|end_day|
| -------- | ---- |---------|-------|
| A        | V    |0        |3      |
| A        | W    |4        |NaN    |
| A        | X    |10       |15     |
| B        | V    |0        |3      |
| B        | W    |4        |NaN    |
| B        | X    |4        |NaN    |
| B        | Y    |10       |15     |
| B        | Z    |11       |Nan    |
```

And here's how I would like the output to look:

```
| patient  | drug |start_day|end_day|
| -------- | ---- |---------|-------|
| A        | V    |0        |3      |
| A        | W    |4        |10     |
| A        | X    |10       |15     |
| B        | V    |0        |3      |
| B        | W    |4        |10     |
| B        | X    |4        |10     |
| B        | Y    |10       |15     |
| B        | Z    |11       |Nan    |
```

Notice a couple of quirks in the example with patient B:

1. Drugs X and Y are on the same timing regimen, both with start_day = 4 and end_day = NaN, so their end_day values should both be updated to the next available start_day that is not on the same regimen. i.e. patient B, drug X start day should be updated to 10, not 4.
2. Drug Z goes from day 11 to day NaN, but is the last drug in patient B's treatment schedule, so it does not need to be updated

Any advice on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once it is not possible to use `fillna()` with both **values** and **method** parameters simultaneously, I don't believe that there is a straightforward solution.

The solution described here has a margin for improvement.

### Creating the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"patient": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"], "drug":["V", "W", "X", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"], "start_day":[0, 4, 10, 0, 4, 4, 10, 11], "end_day":[3, None, 15, 3, None, None, 15, None]})

print(df)
  patient drug  start_day  end_day
0       A    V          0      3.0
1       A    W          4      NaN
2       A    X         10     15.0
3       B    V          0      3.0
4       B    W          4      NaN
5       B    X          4      NaN
6       B    Y         10     15.0
7       B    Z         11      NaN
```

### Trying with `fillna(method='bfill')`

The `bfill` method will populate NaN values with the next non-NaN value.

```
df["end_day"].fillna(method='bfill')
0     3.0
1    15.0
2    15.0
3     3.0
4    15.0
5    15.0
6    15.0
7     NaN
Name: end_day, dtype: float64
```

As described above, it would fill with the values of the same column.

### Trying with `fillna(using the start_day column)`

```
df["end_day"].fillna(df["start_day"])
0     3.0
1     4.0
2    15.0
3     3.0
4     4.0
5     4.0
6    15.0
7    11.0
Name: end_day, dtype: float64
```

As we can see, each NaN was filled with the `start_day` value of the same index.

### Trying to put both tries together

```
df["end_day"].fillna(df["start_day"], method='bfill')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4517, in fillna
    return super().fillna(
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6012, in fillna
    value, method = validate_fillna_kwargs(value, method)
  File "/Users/XXXX/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_validators.py", line 347, in validate_fillna_kwargs
    raise ValueError("Cannot specify both 'value' and 'method'.")
ValueError: Cannot specify both 'value' and 'method'.
```

As we expected:

> ValueError: Cannot specify both 'value' and 'method'.

So, the very "ugly" solution for this case:

```
df["new_end_day"] = df["end_day"]

i = 0
while i < rows:
    if str(df["end_day"][i]) == "nan":
        j = i + 1
        while j < rows and str(df["end_day"][j]) == "nan":
            j += 1
        for n in range(i, j):
            try:
                df["new_end_day"][n] = df["start_day"][j]
            except:
                pass
    i += 1
```

The result would be

```
print(df)

  patient drug  start_day  end_day  new_end_day
0       A    V          0      3.0          3.0
1       A    W          4      NaN         10.0
2       A    X         10     15.0         15.0
3       B    V          0      3.0          3.0
4       B    W          4      NaN         10.0
5       B    X          4      NaN         10.0
6       B    Y         10     15.0         15.0
7       B    Z         11      NaN          NaN
```

There is no need to create a `new_end_day` column, and you can do the same for the  `end_day` column.

This can take a while for huge DataFrames

**UPDATE** based on [this](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496811/substituindo-valores-nan-pelo-subsequente-not-nan-de-outra-coluna/496988#496988)

### THIS WORKS.

This will do the job

```
df['end_day_1'] = df['end_day'].fillna(df['start_day'].mask(df['end_day'].isna()).bfill())
```

The output would be:

```
print(df)

patient drug  start_day  end_day  end_day_1
0       A    V          0      3.0        3.0
1       A    W          4      NaN       10.0
2       A    X         10     15.0       15.0
3       B    V          0      3.0        3.0
4       B    W          4      NaN       10.0
5       B    X          4      NaN       10.0
6       B    Y         10     15.0       15.0
7       B    Z         11      NaN        NaN
```

As I wrote at the beginning, this has room for improvement.

Comment: You can use `fillna()` but you need to substitute with `df['start_day'].shift(-1)`

Comment: The issue with the questions is that it is not a fixed -1 shift. Murth would like to replace NaN values from one column with another column values following some rules.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think we need to do a lot of things to get the previous value.

In pandas, you can give shift(-1) to get previous row and shift(1) to get next row. In this case we need previous row of another column. So just give column name and shift (-1). That way you can get the right value to substitute the `nan` values.

Please use this.

```
df['end_day'] = df['end_day'].fillna(df['start_day'].shift(-1))
```

Here's the before and after:

**Before:**

```
  patient drug  start_day  end_day
0       A    V          0      3.0
1       A    W          4      NaN
2       A    X         10     15.0
3       B    V          0      3.0
4       B    W          4      NaN
5       B    X          4      NaN
6       B    Y         10     15.0
7       B    Z         11      NaN
```

**After:**

```
  patient drug  start_day  end_day
0       A    V          0      3.0
1       A    W          4     10.0
2       A    X         10     15.0
3       B    V          0      3.0
4       B    W          4      4.0
5       B    X          4     10.0
6       B    Y         10     15.0
7       B    Z         11      NaN
```